GitHub API for deleting an environment does not work
While I can see the list of deployments using:
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/deployments

And I see the name of the environments that I have deployed to them in the JSON response of the above request; I cannot see the list of environments using:
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/environments

My aim is to delete one of the environments—that I already deleted all its deployments—by using:
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  --method DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/environments/ENVIRONMENT_NAME

However, for both of the recent APIs, I get this error:
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/deployments/environments#delete-an-environment",
  "status": "404"
}
gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)

Note: I replace OWNER and REPO correctly.

Did you URL-encode the environment name?

No, it has just a dash in between.

So you see the environment in the UI, but not in the API response, right?

Yes. I can also see the environments in the response of
GET /repos/OWNER/REPO/deployments

And when you say "I cannot see the list of environments", do you mean you don't see any environments in that response at all?

It provides 404 errors. Either for listing environments or deleting one of them by name that I see in the webapp.

So gh api repos/OWNER/REPO/environments 404s? That definitely shouldn't be the case.

Is the repo public per chance?

No, it is private.
